# How to Calculate Values of Options from Different Select

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate values of selected indexes. Dropdowns are dynamic so I might have 3 dropdowns, 5 dropdowns or 8 dropdowns. When I try to calculate values of selected indexes, I get `NaN`. Am I missing something?

```js
function calculate() {
var calculationSpan = document.getElementById("calculationSpan");
var add;
  var selects = document.querySelectorAll(".rooms");
     selects.forEach(function (select) {
       var roomsOfType = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
          if (roomsOfType != 0) {
            add = parseInt(add) + parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
            }
       });
                   calculationSpan.innerHTML = add;
}
```

```html
<select class="rooms">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>


<select class="rooms">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
<option value="5">Five</option>
<option value="6">Six</option>
</select>

<select class="rooms">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
<option value="4">Four</option>
</select>

<button onclick="calculate()">
Calculate
</button>
<span id="calculationSpan"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need a start value for `add`.

```
var add = 0;
```

And you have to borrow [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), because `selects` is an array like object, but not an array.

You need [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for using `selects` as `thisArg`.

```
[].forEach.call(selects, function (/* ... */ ))
```

```js
function calculate() {
    var calculationSpan = document.getElementById("calculationSpan"),
        add = 0,
        selects = document.querySelectorAll(".rooms");

    [].forEach.call(selects, function (select) {
        var roomsOfType = +select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        if (roomsOfType) {
            add += roomsOfType;
        }
    });
    calculationSpan.innerHTML = add;
}
```

```html
<select class="rooms"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option></select>
<select class="rooms"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option><option value="4">Four</option><option value="5">Five</option><option value="6">Six</option></select>
<select class="rooms"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option><option value="3">Three</option><option value="4">Four</option></select>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
<span id="calculationSpan"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know about `[].forEach.call()`. I will be verifying your answer in 6mins